# Как делать такое в 24bitrix?

Tags: битрикс24, crm

И за многих проектов и основы оплаты введу все свои сделки в CRM Битрикс 24. И у меня вопрос как сделать следующее. Есть сделка на условно 12 000 рублей. Я добавляю ее. И перевожу в работу. Делаю 50% и заказчик оплачивает 50% суммы. Можно ли как то сделать что бы эту сделку и сумму как то увидеть что он заплатил , сколько осталось. ЕДинственный выход который я нашел это разделять одну сделку на пару сделок по меньше и с ними работать. Есть более легкий способ?

Comment: Вы сами указываете, что выполнено 50% и оплачено 50%. Или при оплате заказчиком есть возможность отследить какой заказ был оплачен?

Comment: Как и где это указать. Я создаю сделку. 12 000. Перевожу ее в работу. Он оплачивает половину. Где мне указать что половину он уже оплатил

Comment: Создать дополнительную таблицу, в которой вы будете заносить все поступления по заказам. Поля таблицы `id, amount, date, id_project` Связь один ко многим. Так у вас появится история всех поступлений.